# Is it possible to run my following code by parallel?

Tags: java, parallel-processing

Actually the following code is doing the gaussian elimination for a matrix. And my job is to try some java concurrency technique to let it be a parallel program. 
However, the problem is that each external loop has the data dependency which comes from the previous loop. And I have try that it is too costly to use the parallel technique inside the external loop. Can someone help me with it? How to let the following code run by parallel? Is there any technique in java concurrency technique can handle with this condition?

```
    for (int i = 0; i <1; i++) {

        int max = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
            if (Math.abs(matrix[j][i]) > Math.abs(matrix[max][i])) {
                max = j; 
            }
        }

        double[] temp = matrix[i]; 
        matrix[i] = matrix[max];
        matrix[max] = temp; 


        for (int k = i + 1; k < N; k++) 
        {
            double alpha = matrix[k][i] / matrix[i][i]; 
            for (int j = i; j < N; j++) 
            {
                matrix[k][j] -= alpha * matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post everything else, like for example what is matrix? What is N? Thanks.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <1; i++)`?? Really? Why not just replace all use of `i` with a `0`, and eliminate the (non-)loop?

Answer (score 0):

The work done by the `k` loop can be made parallel, since the modified data is non-overlapping.

Simply delegate the work done by the body of the loop to a thread.

Easiest way is to use a Java 8 parallel stream, i.e. replace the `k` loop with:

```
final int ii = i; // since 'i' is not effectively-final
IntStream.range(ii + 1, N).parallel().forEach(k -> {
    double alpha = matrix[k][ii] / matrix[ii][ii];
    for (int j = ii; j < N; j++) {
        matrix[k][j] -= alpha * matrix[ii][j];
    }
});
```